# How to return the input document in $facet

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, facet

I am looking for a smart way to return the input document in a `$facet` aggregation. Something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { <pipeline stage 1> },
   { <pipeline stage 2> },
   {
      $facet:
         {
            outputField1: [ output of <pipeline stage 2> ],
            outputField2: [ { <pipeline stage 3> } ]
         }
   }
])
```

I tried stuff like `outputField1: [ $$CURRENT ]` but did not work.

Actually I found two workarounds, but I wonder if there is a smarter way of doing it.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { <pipeline stage 1> },
   {
      $facet:
         {
            outputField1: [ { <pipeline stage 2> } ],
            outputField2: [ { <pipeline stage 2> }, { <pipeline stage 3> } ]
         }
   }
])


db.collection.aggregate([
   { <pipeline stage 1> },
   { <pipeline stage 2> },
   {
      $facet:
         {
            outputField1: [ { $unset: "a_dummy_field_which_does_not_exist" } ],
            outputField2: [ { <pipeline stage 3> } ]
         }
   }
])
```

Comment: Doing this `{ <pipeline stage 2> }` twice in either of `outputField1` & `outputField2` is not needed. About your second option not sure what's going on with it/whether it's optimized or not - unless we see your queries :-) You can use my answer as it's like basic `.find()` without any filters which would return all the docs passing thru as is..

Comment: Yes, that's why I called it "workaround"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this `{ $match: {} }` as well to return the current document as is :

```
{
    $facet:
    {
        outputField1: [{ $match: {} }],
        outputField2: [ { <pipeline stage 3> } ] } } }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, `{ $match: {} }` is also like a `null` operation. Actually I would expect to use a global constant - perhaps it does not exist.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : this is the only thing I could think of, cause if you wanted to use any operator then it should has to be used in a stage like ‘$project’ which would create an array outputField1 of objects. Or you can project a field with group + push & root but that as well creates an object inside outputField1 array !!